# The method countTrue(boolean[]) in the type GUI is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, boolean, arguments

this is the error :

"The method countTrue(boolean[]) in the type GUI is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)"
, the error is in the last line , but i dont get why.

```
public class GUI {
    
    public GUI(){
        
    }
    
    public static int countTrue(boolean[] arr) {
        int count = 0;
        for (boolean element : arr) {
            if (element == true ) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        return count ;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int x = GUI.countTrue([true, false, false, true, false]);
            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New array should be declared as below:

`int x = GUI.countTrue(new boolean[]{true, false, false, true, false});`

OR

you can use varargs and declare your method as:
`public static int countTrue(boolean... arr)`

and then call it as:
`int x = GUI.countTrue(true, false, false, true, false);`

Also you can simplify `if (element == true)` to just `if (element)`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of boolean [] in your countTrue method, declare the parameter as boolean...